# C# WPF MVVM - How to populate ObservableCollection then later load data in listview?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, binding

so, i have a mainviewmodel and a secondviewmodel, my ObservableCollection is in the secondviewmodel, but i want to populate it from mainviewmodel and then later in the program i would want to load a popup with a listview that has the data loaded from earlier. I don't want to add data in the list from the View. I was thinking about this, until now only if i add data from the secondviewmodel shows on the popup when i open it.

### XAMl

```
<Grid Background="Gainsboro" >
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <vm:AdminViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding GenerateCommand}"  Grid.Column="2" Height="30" Width="55" x:Name="btnGenerate" Margin="5,5,5,0" FontSize="8.5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Generate"/>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">


            <Border   BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Grid DataContext="{Binding}" Width="300" Height="300" Background="Gainsboro" Margin="0">
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform x:Name="theTransform" />
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <Button Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding AbortCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Abort"/>
                    <TreeView>
                        <TreeView.DataContext>
                            <vm:ReportViewModel/>
                        </TreeView.DataContext>
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Error" IsExpanded="True">
                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Error}">

                            </ListView>
                        </TreeViewItem>
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Warning" IsExpanded="True">
                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Warning}">

                            </ListView>
                        </TreeViewItem>
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Information" IsExpanded="True">

                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Information}">
                            </ListView>
                        </TreeViewItem>
                    </TreeView>


                </Grid>
            </Border>


    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

### This is the main view model

```
class AdminViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private RelayCommand generateCommand;
    public RelayCommand GenerateCommand { get { return generateCommand; } }
    private ReportViewModel rvm;
    public AdminViewModel()
    {
        generateCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { Generate(); }); //bind UI button to this command
        rvm = new ReportViewModel();
    }
    private  void Generate()
    {
        if (CadFilePath == string.Empty)
        {
            rvm.LogError("Warning", "This is a warning"); //this should add the string "This is warning" in the ObservableCollection called Warning in the secondviewmodel

        }
    }
}
```

### Second Viewmodel

```
class ReportViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> error;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Error
    {
        get { return error; }
        set
        {
            error = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Error");
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<string> warning;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Warning
    {
        get { return warning; }
        set
        {
            warning = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Warning");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> information;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Information
    {
        get { return information; }
        set
        {
            information = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Information");
        }
    }

    public ReportViewModel()
    {
        error = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        warning = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        information = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Warning.Add("Warning"); //this is showing in UI
        Warning.Add("Warning2"); //this is showing in UI
        Error.Add("404"); // this is showing in UI
        Information.Add("INFO"); //this is showing in UI
    }

    public void LogError(string severity, string err)
    {
        if (severity == "Warning")
        {
            Warning.Add(err);
        }
        if (severity == "Error")
        {
            Error.Add(err);
        }
        if (severity == "Information")
        {
            Information.Add(err);
        }

    }
```

Comment: what have you tried? what was the error code? please ask a specific question which can be answered in less than a book!

Comment: I'm not getting any errors it's just not showing any values in the listview, i can post the code if you want

Comment: Please do! and please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you, i will read it. I updated the question with the code, thanks again.

Comment: thanks for adding your source code. however, this question still has very poor quality. I'm not sure which part of the question am I supposed to approach. why am I seeing a popup. and what is the purpose of the relay command? I don't think any of these help with your actual question. can you simplify your question and remove **all unnecessary parts**?

Comment: The relay command is used to bind a button from UI to the method Generate in the AdminViewModel. This Generate method should add a string in one of the 3 collection that i have with this line of code " rvm.LogError("Warning", "This is a warning"); " and also make the popup appear in which the string above should now be added and visible but it's not. Hope it's more clear know, i will add few more comments in the code.

Comment: I simplified your question a little bit. there is absolutely no need for a popup and a checkbox and a (not-implemented by the way) IsChecked property for this particular question. so I removed them all. please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating another instance of view model in this line: (remove this)

```
<TreeView.DataContext>
    <vm:ReportViewModel/>
</TreeView.DataContext>
```

What you should have done is to read an existing instance of the view model instead: (add this)

```
<TreeView DataContext="{Binding Rvm}">
```

And obviously you'd need to have a public property for `ReportViewModel` in `AdminViewModel` for that to work: (add this)

```
public ReportViewModel Rvm { get { return rvm; } }
```

### edit

you need `Rvm` defined like that because **the binding source must be a `public property`**

you won't need to notify changes for `Rvm` (and also for the 3 collections) since you only set their value in the constructor and you never change them later on.

A good practice for `ObservableCollection` is to create a snippet out of the following code:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> warning = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> Warning { get { return warning; } }
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver, it works, thank you. Can you explain me why did i need a property for the viewmodel? I'm guessing that this way the treeview gets the data but i thought if i set the datacontext should do the job and one more thing, can you tell me a good place to learn WPF and MVVM i would really like to understand better.

Comment: ur welcome :-) I updated my answer. you can learn more about WPF and MVVM in websites like code project and follow best practices and try not to rely on easy frameworks such as telerik.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but can you check the post again, i've added another question because i made a modification i can't get it to work :) Thank you!

Comment: @dNj17 please do not post followups as an answer. this is not a forum.